# SSH behind a NAT enabled router

Tags: networking, server, 14.04, ssh

I have a netgear router, and i installed openssh, now when i try

```
ssh deadman@192.168.0.4
```

My ssh works fine and i am able to enter to the ssh terminal
But when i try it with a remote terminal like

```
ssh deadman@117.192.213.115
```

I dont see anything , 
if i try

```
deadman -W deadman@117.192.213.115
```

i get

```
Bad stdio forwarding specification 'deadman@117.192.213.115'
```

note that 117.192.213.115 is my routers ip - [image]

and in my router settings i have enabled port forwarding  -

[image]

Comment: // , I have the same problem, with the exact same router type.

Answer (score 0):

- Try pinging your IP. Does the IP actually exist? (It didn't when I tried and you getting no response whatsoever suggests your IP may have changed).
- Maybe your router needs to be rebooted for the settings to take effect?
- Maybe your ISP blocks port 22. In that case try forwarding your internal port 22 to another external port and then use `ssh deadman@<your IP>:<port>`

Tip: You shouldn't publicly mention your WAN-facing IP-address. You'll just invite less friendly folks to try and break in.

If you are not sure whether your ISP blocks a certain port, you might want to test that by visiting the site `grc.com`. Once there find their service called "Shields Up!". That lets you test your router and they also have a port probe showing you which ports are open/closed/stealthed. If port 22 shows closed or stealthed while it is being forwarded it's likely being blocked somewhere upstream. Try a higher portnumber (>10 000)

Comment: sorry for the late reply and yeah I got the advice and my ISP had dynamic IP so that's why I immediately changed it so that the given IP doesn't work anymore. Also the error was I think as explained on server fault that I need direct access to internet for this. I cannot sit behind nat and do this. It seems that's why I got no response while someone who was trying to solve my problem got response

Comment: @deadman : The NAT router is not the problem. You set-up the router  OK. If you know the IP it will work. Your router just needs to hang on to the IP long enough. My ISP has dynamic IPs, but as long as my router stays connected to the Internet, the IP won't change. Don't switch off your modem or router, and your IP will remain.

Comment: // , I have a similar problem, as all ports I open still show up as stealthed. 

For example, the last port I tried, 52222, shows up as stealthed: http://i.imgur.com/Pzt2VU6.png

Comment: // , Everything works on my local network, though.

Comment: @Misogynist : Please be aware that LAN-side ports are not the same as WAN-side ports. If your problem remains, and you can't resolve it with the info provided here (or in similar threads) I suggest you open a new question instead of hijacking an existing one. No offence intended.